# SharePoint CSOM - Load HasUniqueRoleAssignment fails all time

Tags: sharepoint, csom

I am getting much confused as where I am doing wrong. I have done it many times before but not sure why its NOT working this time. Here is a code;

```
dynamic fileOrFolder;
if (model.IsFolder)
    fileOrFolder = _clientContext.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeUrl);
else
    fileOrFolder = _clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeUrl);
```

I have tried ALL below but nothing worked;

```
_clientContext.Load(fileOrFolder, item => item.Include(file => file.ListItemAllFields));

dynamic blhasUniquePermission = fileOrFolder.ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments;
```

OR

```
_clientContext.Load(fileOrFolder.ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments);
```

OR

```
_clientContext.Load(fileOrFolder.ListItemAllFields,
    items => items.Include(
        item => item.Id,
        item => item.DisplayName,
        item => item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments));
```

OR

```
_clientContext.Load(fileOrFolder.ListItemAllFields, "Include(HasUniqueRoleAssignments)");
_clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
```

Everytime it is immediatly throwing error on either the Load line itself or on ExecuteQuery. We deffo know the property is there in ListItemAllFields collection then why its doing it?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you used `dynamic` keyword in order to hack C# into letting you create `fileOrFolder` variable and store instance of one of two unrelated types inside.

Not only it's weird, but by doing so you've also crippled IntelliSense and compiler.

Take this line:

```
_clientContext.Load(fileOrFolder, item => item.Include(file => file.ListItemAllFields));
```

It probably throws in runtime, because there is no `Include` method on neither `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.File` or `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Folder` type. If you didn't use `dynamic`, you'd get clear compiler error instead.

This one:

```
_clientContext.Load(fileOrFolder.ListItemAllFields.HasUniqueRoleAssignments);
```

doesn't work, because `_clientContext.Load` takes instance of `Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientObject`. But again, compiler doesn't know what the argument is, because it comes from dynamic object. Instead of red squiggly in editor, you get runtime error.

That should work:

```
ListItem itemAndOnlyItem = null;
if (model.IsFolder)
{
    var folder = _clientContext.Web.GetFolderByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeUrl);
    itemAndOnlyItem = folder.ListItemAllFields;
}
else
{
    var file = _clientContext.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(serverRelativeUrl);
    itemAndOnlyItem = file.ListItemAllFields;
}

_clientContext.Load(itemAndOnlyItem,
    item => item.HasUniqueRoleAssignments);
_clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

var result = itemAndOnlyItem.HasUniqueRoleAssignments;
```